# DIV Auto scroll not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I have a div that autoscrolls to the bottom. But whenever a lot of smileys are used in one chat post, the auto scroll stops working correctly, it scrolls 2 lines from the bottom.

I did try using this..

```
 $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal');
```

But the div autoloads every 3 seconds, so everytime it loads the animation effect would show.

What can I use in place to ensure it works?

Here is the full function...

```
setInterval(function loadLog(){     
        var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").prop("scrollHeight") - 20;
        $.ajax({
            url: "log.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){        
                $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div               
                var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").prop("scrollHeight") - 20; //Scroll height after the request  
                $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div

            },
        });
    }, 3500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){scroller()}, 3500);
```

```
function scroller(){
$("#chatbox").load("log.php");
$("#chatbox").each( function(){
var scrollHeight = Math.max(this.scrollHeight, this.clientHeight);
this.scrollTop = scrollHeight - this.clientHeight;
});
}
```